# Can a Laurent series be found for $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ in the region $0<|z+1|<2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, laurent-series

I know that a Laurent series can be found for $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ in the region $0<|z+1|<1$, but can a Laurent series be found for $0<|z+1|<2$?

I am confused because in the region $0<|z+1|<1$ the Laurent series is

$$
\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac{1}{(z+1)}\frac{1}{(1+(1+z))}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac{1}{(z+1)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(z+1)^n
$$
$$
\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(z+1)^{n-1}
$$

but I am not sure how this will differ for $0<|z+1|<2$.

Comment: The domains where it makes sense to write down a Laurent series is domains where $f$ is analytic. Your $f$ has a pole at $z=-1$ and $z=-2$ so you can have a Laurent series on $0 < |z+1| < 1$ and on $|z+1| > 1$, but not on the domain you ask for. If you imagine having such a series then it should converge for $|z+1| = 1$, which is impossible as we have a pole at $z=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: How would that help?

Comment: It would give $f(z)$ as a sum of two simpler functions, each of which having a much easier Laurent expansion.

Answer (score 0):

**Every** holomorphic function $f$ on an annulus (or a punctured disk) has a (unique) Laurent series. By uniqueness, however you find the coefficients, if it actually converges to $f$ it is $f$'s Laurent series.

The thing is: is $f$ actually holormophic in that annulus?

Comment: So how can I go about finding a Laurent series for $f(z)$ in the region $0<|z+1|<2$?

Comment: The thing is: is $f$ actually holomorphic in that annulus? What if you take $z=-2$?